# shopping cart Magento2 REST API and Front-end

Tags: magento2

I was able to sign in using /rest/V1/integration/customer/token and add items to cart. How do I view the cart(items I added using REST API) from front-end?

I want synchronize api cart with cart frontend.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was posted a while ago but I will leave the answer for a reference.

Magento keeps products you put to the cart on the server side. If you log in on the front-end as the same customer as using REST API, you should be able to see the products in the cart.

It works on a clean installation of Magento 2, an example of which you can find under the following [link](https://demo1-m2.mage.direct/). Credentials are:

- login: `roni_cost@example.com`
- password: `roni_cost3@example.com`

If it does not work on your instance, you need to check if nothing changes the default behaviour.